# What does null check operator used on a null value mean in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

[Here I am getting this error in  _formKey.currentState!.save(); this code please help me to resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnMdN.png)

I am new to flutter and I dont have an idea about this

Comment: `currentState!` means that you are asserting that `currentState` cannot logically be `null` at that point.  The runtime error means that `currentState` *is* actually `null`, so that assertion is not true.

Comment: How you wrap your widget with form widget?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Your code `_formKey.currentState!` is telling the system `_formKey.currentState` is not null but when it is called, `_formKey.currentState` is null. That's why you got the error.

Make you have declared `_formKey` in your class and assigned it to a `Form` widget before you call `_formKey.currentState!`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // Declare _formKey

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey, // Assign to Form widget
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('your other widget'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```